# Build fails when using metamask sdk in Unity WebGL environment

Tags: metamask, unity-webgl

Unity version : 2021.3.27f1

[Metamask SDK version](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/decentralization/infrastructure/metamask-246786#releases) : 1.1.2

I tried to build the project by installing only the metamask package in the initialization state, but it failed.

If the build fails, the console window displays the following error.

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js failed with output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 3571, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 3564, in main
    ret = run(args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 1082, in run
    phase_post_link(options, wasm_target, wasm_target, target)
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 2400, in phase_post_link
    phase_emscript(options, in_wasm, wasm_target, memfile)
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 2428, in phase_emscript
    emscripten.run(in_wasm, wasm_target, final_js, memfile)
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 830, in run
    emscript(in_wasm, out_wasm, outfile_js, memfile, shared.DEBUG)
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 308, in emscript
    glue, forwarded_data = compile_settings()
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 178, in compile_settings
    cwd=path_from_root('src'), env=env)
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 216, in run_js_tool
    return check_call(command, *args, **kw).stdout
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 202, in check_call
    return run_process(cmd, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 97, in run_process
    ret = subprocess.run(cmd, check=check, input=input, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\subprocess.py", line 474, in run
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\subprocess.py", line 926, in communicate
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 1049063: illegal multibyte sequence
```

In order to check if there is a problem with the project version or setting, the installed package was removed and built, and it was completed normally.

Is there a solution or something to check about the current situation?